# kubernetes 1.18 Stacked control plane and etcd nodes unable to add second ETCD node

Tags: kubernetes, etcd3

I am trying to setup  3 nodes Kubernets 1.18 on CentOS 8 with Containerd. following Stacked control plane and etcd nodes (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/) document, I was able to setup the primary master with Calico CNI successfully.

When I add second control-plane node, while adding second ETCD membership step, its crashing the primary ETCD container because of this whole cluster came down.  not sure why its not able to add second ETCD member. firewall is disabled on my hosts

**Here is my configuration**

```
- kube-cp-1.com, 10.10.1.1
- kube-cp-2.com, 10.10.1.2
- kube-cp-3.com, 10.10.1.3
- lb.kube-cp.com, 10.10.1.4
```

**kubeadm-config.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.10.1.1
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
  name: kube-cp-1.com
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
    extraArgs:
      listen-client-urls: "https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://10.10.1.1:2379"
      advertise-client-urls: "https://10.10.1.1:2379"
      listen-peer-urls: "https://10.10.1.1:2380"
      initial-advertise-peer-urls: "https://10.10.1.1:2380"
      initial-cluster: "kube-cp-1.com=https://10.10.1.1:2380"
    serverCertSANs:
    - kube-cp-1.com
    - kube-cp-2.com
    - kube-cp-3.com
    - localhost
    - 127.0.0.1
    - 10.10.1.1
    - 10.10.1.2
    - 110.10.1.3
    - 10.10.1.1
    - lb.kube-cp.com
    peerCertSANs:
    - kube-cp-1.com
    - kube-cp-2.com
    - kube-cp-3.com
    - localhost
    - 127.0.0.1
    - 10.10.1.1
    - 10.10.1.2
    - 110.10.1.3
    - 10.10.1.1
    - lb.kube-cp.com
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
apiServerCertSANs:
- "lb.kube-cp.com"
controlPlaneEndpoint: "10.10.1.1:6443"
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.236.0.0/12
  podSubnet: 10.236.0.0/16
scheduler: {}
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs"
```

**init fist master**

```
kubeadm init --upload-certs --config k8s-nprd.kubeadm-init.yaml
```

**adding second master node**

```
   kubeadm join 10.10.1.1:6443 --token abcdef.0123456789abcdef \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:4823caf8f50f531ba1bd7ee6681411cfac923ead603a805f33a3a667fcfb62a4 \
    --control-plane --certificate-key a3005aca06076d93233becae71c600a34fa914aefa9e360c3f8b64092e1c43e5 --cri-socket /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

**message from kubeadm join**

```
I0406 10:25:45.903249    6984 manifests.go:91] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
W0406 10:25:45.903292    6984 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
I0406 10:25:45.903473    6984 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler"
I0406 10:25:45.903941    6984 manifests.go:121] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[check-etcd] Checking that the etcd cluster is healthy
I0406 10:25:45.904727    6984 local.go:78] [etcd] Checking etcd cluster health
I0406 10:25:45.904745    6984 local.go:81] creating etcd client that connects to etcd pods
I0406 10:25:45.904756    6984 etcd.go:178] retrieving etcd endpoints from "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls" annotation in etcd Pods
I0406 10:25:45.912390    6984 etcd.go:102] etcd endpoints read from pods: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:25:45.924703    6984 etcd.go:250] etcd endpoints read from etcd: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:25:45.924732    6984 etcd.go:120] update etcd endpoints: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:25:45.938129    6984 kubelet.go:111] [kubelet-start] writing bootstrap kubelet config file at /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
I0406 10:25:45.940638    6984 kubelet.go:145] [kubelet-start] Checking for an existing Node in the cluster with name "kube-cp-2.com" and status "Ready"
I0406 10:25:45.942529    6984 kubelet.go:159] [kubelet-start] Stopping the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.18" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...
I0406 10:25:46.597353    6984 cert_rotation.go:137] Starting client certificate rotation controller
I0406 10:25:46.599553    6984 kubelet.go:194] [kubelet-start] preserving the crisocket information for the node
I0406 10:25:46.599572    6984 patchnode.go:30] [patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information "/run/containerd/containerd.sock" to the Node API object "kube-cp-2.com" as an annotation
I0406 10:26:01.608756    6984 local.go:130] creating etcd client that connects to etcd pods
I0406 10:26:01.608782    6984 etcd.go:178] retrieving etcd endpoints from "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls" annotation in etcd Pods
I0406 10:26:01.613158    6984 etcd.go:102] etcd endpoints read from pods: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:26:01.621527    6984 etcd.go:250] etcd endpoints read from etcd: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:26:01.621569    6984 etcd.go:120] update etcd endpoints: https://10.10.1.1:2379
I0406 10:26:01.621577    6984 local.go:139] Adding etcd member: https://10.10.1.2:2380
[etcd] Announced new etcd member joining to the existing etcd cluster
I0406 10:26:01.631714    6984 local.go:145] Updated etcd member list: [{kube-cp-2.com https://10.10.1.2:2380} {kube-cp-1.com https://10.10.1.1:2380}]
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for "etcd"
[etcd] Waiting for the new etcd member to join the cluster. This can take up to 40s
I0406 10:26:01.632669    6984 etcd.go:500] [etcd] attempting to see if all cluster endpoints ([https://10.10.1.1:2379 https://10.10.1.2:2379]) are available 1/8
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
I0406 10:26:41.650088    6984 etcd.go:480] Failed to get etcd status for https://10.10.1.2:2379: failed to dial endpoint https://10.10.1.2:2379 with maintenance client: context deadline exceeded
```

**Primary ETCD log message, while adding second node.**

```
crictl logs -f b127c56d13d5f                                                                                                        
[WARNING] Deprecated '--logger=capnslog' flag is set; use '--logger=zap' flag instead
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587582 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.4.3
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587641 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 3cf2f69b5
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587646 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.12.12
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587648 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587652 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 4, total number of available CPUs is 4
[WARNING] Deprecated '--logger=capnslog' flag is set; use '--logger=zap' flag instead
2020-04-06 14:05:10.587713 I | embed: peerTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key, trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-au
th = true, crl-file =
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588321 I | embed: name = kube-cp-1.com
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588335 I | embed: data dir = /var/lib/etcd
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588339 I | embed: member dir = /var/lib/etcd/member
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588341 I | embed: heartbeat = 100ms
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588344 I | embed: election = 1000ms
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588347 I | embed: snapshot count = 10000
2020-04-06 14:05:10.588353 I | embed: advertise client URLs = https://10.10.1.1:2379
2020-04-06 14:05:10.595691 I | etcdserver: starting member 9fe7e24231cce76d in cluster bd17ed771bd8406b
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d switched to configuration voters=()
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became follower at term 0
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: newRaft 9fe7e24231cce76d [peers: [], term: 0, commit: 0, applied: 0, lastindex: 0, lastterm: 0]
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became follower at term 1
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d switched to configuration voters=(11522426945581934445)
2020-04-06 14:05:10.606487 W | auth: simple token is not cryptographically signed
2020-04-06 14:05:10.613683 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 3.4.3, cluster version: to_be_decided]
2020-04-06 14:05:10.614928 I | etcdserver: 9fe7e24231cce76d as single-node; fast-forwarding 9 ticks (election ticks 10)
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d switched to configuration voters=(11522426945581934445)
2020-04-06 14:05:10.615341 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 9fe7e24231cce76d [https://10.10.1.1:2380] to cluster bd17ed771bd8406b
2020-04-06 14:05:10.616288 I | embed: ClientTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key, trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-c
ert-auth = true, crl-file =
2020-04-06 14:05:10.616414 I | embed: listening for metrics on http://127.0.0.1:2381
2020-04-06 14:05:10.616544 I | embed: listening for peers on 10.10.1.1:2380
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 1
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d received MsgVoteResp from 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became leader at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:05:10 INFO: raft.node: 9fe7e24231cce76d elected leader 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 2
2020-04-06 14:05:10.798941 I | etcdserver: setting up the initial cluster version to 3.4
2020-04-06 14:05:10.799837 N | etcdserver/membership: set the initial cluster version to 3.4
2020-04-06 14:05:10.799882 I | etcdserver/api: enabled capabilities for version 3.4
2020-04-06 14:05:10.799904 I | etcdserver: published {Name:kube-cp-1.com ClientURLs:[https://10.10.1.1:2379]} to cluster bd17ed771bd8406b
2020-04-06 14:05:10.800014 I | embed: ready to serve client requests


raft2020/04/06 14:26:01 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d switched to configuration voters=(11306080513102511778 11522426945581934445)
2020-04-06 14:26:01.629134 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 9ce744531170fea2 [https://10.10.1.2:2380] to cluster bd17ed771bd8406b
2020-04-06 14:26:01.629159 I | rafthttp: starting peer 9ce744531170fea2...
2020-04-06 14:26:01.629184 I | rafthttp: started HTTP pipelining with peer 9ce744531170fea2
2020-04-06 14:26:01.630090 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (writer)
2020-04-06 14:26:01.630325 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (writer)
2020-04-06 14:26:01.631552 I | rafthttp: started peer 9ce744531170fea2
2020-04-06 14:26:01.631581 I | rafthttp: added peer 9ce744531170fea2
2020-04-06 14:26:01.631594 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (stream MsgApp v2 reader)
2020-04-06 14:26:01.631826 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (stream Message reader)
2020-04-06 14:26:02.849514 W | etcdserver: failed to reach the peerURL(https://10.10.1.2:2380) of member 9ce744531170fea2 (Get https://10.10.1.2:2380/version: dial tcp 192.168.80.1
30:2380: connect: connection refused)
2020-04-06 14:26:02.849541 W | etcdserver: cannot get the version of member 9ce744531170fea2 (Get https://10.10.1.2:2380/version: dial tcp 10.10.1.2:2380: connect: connection refus
ed)
raft2020/04/06 14:26:02 WARN: 9fe7e24231cce76d stepped down to follower since quorum is not active
raft2020/04/06 14:26:02 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became follower at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:26:02 INFO: raft.node: 9fe7e24231cce76d lost leader 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:26:04 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 2
raft2020/04/06 14:26:04 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 3
raft2020/04/06 14:26:04 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d received MsgVoteResp from 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 3
raft2020/04/06 14:26:04 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d [logterm: 2, index: 3741] sent MsgVote request to 9ce744531170fea2 at term 3
raft2020/04/06 14:26:06 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 3
raft2020/04/06 14:26:06 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 4
raft2020/04/06 14:26:06 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d received MsgVoteResp from 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 4
raft2020/04/06 14:26:06 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d [logterm: 2, index: 3741] sent MsgVote request to 9ce744531170fea2 at term 4
2020-04-06 14:26:06.631923 W | rafthttp: health check for peer 9ce744531170fea2 could not connect: dial tcp 10.10.1.2:2380: connect: connection refused
2020-04-06 14:26:06.632008 W | rafthttp: health check for peer 9ce744531170fea2 could not connect: dial tcp 10.10.1.2:2380: connect: connection refused
raft2020/04/06 14:26:07 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 4
raft2020/04/06 14:26:07 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 5
raft2020/04/06 14:26:07 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d received MsgVoteResp from 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 5
raft2020/04/06 14:26:07 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d [logterm: 2, index: 3741] sent MsgVote request to 9ce744531170fea2 at term 5
raft2020/04/06 14:26:08 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 5
raft2020/04/06 14:26:08 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 6


2020-04-06 14:27:11.684519 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/events/kube-system/kube-scheduler-kube-cp-2.com.1603412b3ca5e3ea\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (7.013696732s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:11 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:11 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:11.684604 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/leases/kube-node-lease/kube-cp-2.com\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (6.216330254s) to
execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:11 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
raft2020/04/06 14:27:12 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d is starting a new election at term 48
raft2020/04/06 14:27:12 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d became candidate at term 49
raft2020/04/06 14:27:12 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d received MsgVoteResp from 9fe7e24231cce76d at term 49
raft2020/04/06 14:27:12 INFO: 9fe7e24231cce76d [logterm: 2, index: 3741] sent MsgVote request to 9ce744531170fea2 at term 49
2020-04-06 14:27:12.632989 N | pkg/osutil: received terminated signal, shutting down...
2020-04-06 14:27:12.633468 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/namespaces/default\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (7.957912936s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.633992 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/health\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (1.649430193s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.637645 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/crd.projectcalico.org/ippools\" range_end:\"/registry/crd.projectcalico.org/ippoolt\" count_only:true " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (6.174043444s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.637888 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/crd.projectcalico.org/ipamconfigs\" range_end:\"/registry/crd.projectcalico.org/ipamconfigt\" count_only:true " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (7.539908265s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.638007 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/services/endpoints/kube-system/kube-scheduler\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (1.967145665s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.638271 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/pods\" range_end:\"/registry/podt\" count_only:true " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (1.809718334s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.638423 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/services/endpoints/kube-system/kube-controller-manager\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (1.963396181s) to execute
2020-04-06 14:27:12.638433 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/horizontalpodautoscalers\" range_end:\"/registry/horizontalpodautoscalert\" count_only:true " with result
"error:context canceled" took too long (6.779544473s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.638462 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/pods/kube-system/kube-controller-manager-kube-cp-1.com\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long
(970.539525ms) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.639866 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/crd.projectcalico.org/clusterinformations/default\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (2.965996315s) to execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-04-06 14:27:12.640009 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/leases/kube-node-lease/kube-cp-1.com\" " with result "error:context canceled" took too long (566.004502ms) to
execute
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: Server.processUnaryRPC failed to write status: connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
WARNING: 2020/04/06 14:27:12 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {10.10.1.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.10.1.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647096 I | etcdserver: skipped leadership transfer for stopping non-leader member
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647188 I | rafthttp: stopping peer 9ce744531170fea2...
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647201 I | rafthttp: stopped streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (writer)
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647209 I | rafthttp: stopped streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (writer)
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647228 I | rafthttp: stopped HTTP pipelining with peer 9ce744531170fea2
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647238 I | rafthttp: stopped streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (stream MsgApp v2 reader)
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647248 I | rafthttp: stopped streaming with peer 9ce744531170fea2 (stream Message reader)
2020-04-06 14:27:12.647260 I | rafthttp: stopped peer 9ce744531170fea2
```

Any help to add seconday etcd node?

Thanks
SR

Comment: that kubeadm config file you created? where in the doc its mentioned to create? can you share the etcd yaml from both master1 and master2..its located /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml

Comment: its in the note section. `Note: The kubeadm init flags --config`

Comment: there is a connection refused error...is the 2nd master node reachable from master1?

Comment: yes, firewall is off. I can second node as worker node with-out any issue.

Comment: Are you trying `Stacked` or `External` etcd? Seems your config file you are using `External` but at the begining you mentioned `Stacked`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: trying `Stacked` only in my configuration file you can see `local`. for External etcd we need to have `external:` entry. also I tried with-out kubeadm config, got the same result.

Comment: I've tried to perform the same steps from the site you posted to reproduce your scenario, but insted centos I'm using Ubuntu. I've create 3 instances on GCP and executed the commands on page, all 3 nodes was successfully add as control-plane. The only issue that I had was with loadbalancer, I need to add one instance per time, because when I added all of them, the kubeadm init fails on the 2nd and 3rd node. The kubernetes version I've tested is 1.18.1. Are you using what cloud provider, and how are you doing the loadbalancer config for api-server?

Comment: @KoopaKiller I am building it on-prem servers. I use `haproxy` as LB, its running only primary node with LB IP. I was testing with `1.18.0`, let give a try for `1.18.1` version

Comment: @sfgroups Any update about your issue? Did you try with Kubernetes 1.18.1?

Comment: @KoopaKiller same issue with `1.18.1` also. I trying to setup external ETCD setup.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue with v1.18.1, and root-caused it to the fact that my control-plane hosts had an incorrectly configured MTU value for the network interface. This was causing the etcdserver pod interactions between the first and subsequent control-plane nodes to timeout, because some network packets were getting silently dropped.

Fixing the MTU allowed me to complete the control-plane setup as advertised.

Details for my setup:

In my case, I was using KVM VMs (launched using LXD) as my control-plane hosts. Because of a DHCP misconfiguration error, the hosts were not receiving the proper MTU, so stayed with the defaul value of 1500 ... which ran into problems with the inter-host overlay network. Reducing the MTU down to 1450 resolved the issue.

If you are interested in additional details about why the MTU misconfiguration manifested in the way it did, I found the following Project Calico issue discussion useful:
https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1709

Comment: trying with external etcd, later I will test with reducing MTU size.